# Custom CP for Members

Tags: control-panel, members, member-details

I'm trying to develop a membership website. I'm using SafeCracker Registration so I can leverage Channels for member data. Once members are registered and verified, I want them to be able to do the following:

- Log in from a customized login page
- Have their own control panel where they can edit their profiles (I'll build the SafeCracker forms); I don't want them seeing the EE CP.
- Use EE's build in emailing system so members can email each other (I don't want to build this myself)

So, my questions are:

1. What is the proper way to customize the login page? The changes I want to implement include mark up changes, content changes, and other design changes.
2. How do I tell EE that when a member of a particular member group logs in that they should be redirected to the customize CP that I plan to build?
3. How do I let my member use EE's email system so that members can email each other? Ideally, I'd like to redo the markup for this (to make it responsive using Twitter Bootstrap), but I'm happy to just use whatever EE has initially as I am concerned it may be too much effort trying to make changes to it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**What is the proper way to customize the login page?.**

Just pop the native [**Login Form Tag**](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/member/index.html#login-form-tag) into your template. You'll want to use the [**Login Redirect extension**](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/login-redirect) to get around the annoying  default "you are logged in" message.

---

**How do I tell EE that when a member of a particular member group logs in that they should be redirected to the customize CP that I plan to build?**

On the Login Form Tag set the `return=""` parameter to a template which will handle the redirecting... ex: `return="members/redirect"`.

Inside that template, setup conditionals to handle the redirects to the unique templates. These conditionals will match the member group of the logged in user.

```
{if "logged_in_group_id" == "1"}{redirect ="members/group1"}{/if}
```

---

**How do I let my member use EE's email system so that members can email each other? Ideally, I'd like to redo the markup for this (to make it responsive using Twitter Bootstrap), but I'm happy to just use whatever EE has initially as I am concerned it may be too much effort trying to make changes to it.**

These are two are worth evaluating for private messaging. I haven't used either of them.

[**Messaging**](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/messaging)
"Messaging is the module for ExpressionEngine 2 that brings all power of Private Messages, Bulletins (public messages) and Buddies/Blocked lists to frontent templates - even with AJAX support!"

**[Friends](http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/friends)**
"Allows your users to create and manage lists of friends, along with complete private messaging, status updates, comment walls, referral tracking, and virtual groups."

Comment: Thanks for the `login form tag` mention. I'm looking into https://objectivehtml.com/authenticate/ as well. I understand now what to do about redirecting my users to the custom CP. Thanks. As for the email system -- I need to study this a bit more.

Comment: The Authenticate addon will work just fine too and has some added pluses.

Answer (score 2):

3) Solspace Friends Module offers access to the messaging system in templates http://www.solspace.com/docs/friends

Comment: $100!!! I need to study this carefully. :) Thanks.