# How do I redirect users to group-specific pages on login?

Tags: conditionals

I have a log-in page that needs to direct users to content based on their member group. Currently it is very simple with just two pages.

I have tried it using the single option and it directs correctly.

Example:

> {exp:member:login_form return="member-area/" }

However, if I introduce a conditional into the mix, it does not redirect correctly:

```
{exp:member:login_form {if member_group == "5"} return="member-area/" {/if} {if member_group == "1" || member_group == "6" || member_group == "7" || member_group == "8"} return="internal-staff-center/" {/if} }
```

I suspect I have overlooked something. I would appreciate any assistance in getting this correctly.

Thanks.

Forrest

Comment: MediaGirl, Sorry but I am afraid you have overstepped your bounds closing out my question without providing any links to a solution. This is marked as an exact duplicate, however, I have not seen any other questions like it and this is the only one I posted.

Comment: I voted to reopen the question, but as look at it now it _does_ look like the [accepted answer in the thread you linked to](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/a/1879/22) in the start of your post includes an answer pretty much the same as Mark's solid answer below. See the part in the duplicate thread starting with "On the Login Form Tag set the return parameter..." So it does seem a duplicate, though maybe not an exact one!

Comment: It seems like same answer, different question. The other question referred to starts with the premise of a custom control panel. This question's scope is limited handling users who log in anywhere in the site.

Comment: Yeah, the other question had a lot going on but the part labelled #2 seems pretty darn similar (redirect particular member groups in a unique way post-login). Still, I'm coming around to your way of thinking again. :) Maybe @Anna can take a look along with other moderators. It's up for debate just how similar a question needs to be to warrant closure! Leaving it open could potentially result in additional good answers. And because of its focus, this is a more findable post.

Comment: I agree that although part of the other question contains similar elements, someone searching for one question may not find the other (especially since the other question asks specifically about login destination for the control panel). Have reopened.

Comment: Thanks, Derek. The other thread's reference to "control panel" _does_ muddy the waters, but FWIW it looks like it was a template-based custom control panel (SafeCracker not the EE CP).

Comment: Reopening works for me. The correct answer is the same for both so for me it was the same question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What if you do:

```
{exp:member:login_form return="member-redirect/" }
```

And then in the `member-redirect` template you have your conditionals:

```
{if member_group == "5"} {redirect="member-area/"} {/if} {if member_group == "1" || member_group == "6" || member_group == "7" || member_group == "8"} {redirect="internal-staff-center/"} {/if}
```

You don't actually have access to your member_group variable when you set up the login form. You haven't logged the user in yet.

Comment: Hi Mark, I see the logic here, however, when I implement it, it gets stuck on the redirect page. I tried placing the redirect conditionals inside html code and alone by itself. Either way, it gets stuck. Any more suggestions on what I am still missing?

Comment: Hi Mark, I figured it out. You have the have the redirect code inside of { }, otherwise it won't work. Thanks.

Comment: Updated so it was clear that the redirects are tags. Please mark as answered?

Comment: Thanks. I wish mediaGirl hadn't closed this as exact duplicate because it is not exactly the same.

Comment: That other question is the same really as is the accepted answer.

Comment: Hi MediaGirl, could I suggest that if there is another question that is similar that you reference that in your comments. A duplicate question should be one that is posted by the same person, not a similar question. It is a bit jarring to have your post closed out like that. Thanks.